# glDrawElements with VBO

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I want to render my vertices with the order defined by an Index Buffer.

If I use

```
glDrawElements(int mode, ByteBuffer indices);
```

everything works fine, but if I want to upload this data to GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER I get a black screen and the glError 1281.

This is my code:

```
public void buildBuffer() {

        //generate VBOs

        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(this.model.getVertexData().size() * 3);
        for (float[] f : this.model.getVertexData()) {
            buffer.put(f);
        }
        buffer.flip();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        ByteBuffer ibuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(3);
        ibuffer.put((byte) 1);
        ibuffer.put((byte) 2);
        ibuffer.put((byte) 3);
        ibuffer.flip();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.iVBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


        glBindVertexArray(this.VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vVBO);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    public void draw() {

        this.shader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(this.VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.iVBO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        Shader.NONE.use();
    }
```

Comment: Indices are 0-based.

Comment: That's not the problem. 1,2,3 is the first triangle of my 3d model

Comment: I believe LWJGL wants a direct Java.nio.Buffer for any data passed to `glBufferData (...)`. It's been my experience with these questions in the past that it will throw an exception if you try to allocate a non-direct buffer. So try: `ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect (3)`. Do the same for your vertex data buffer.

Comment: Ändert leider alles nichts.

Comment: For future reference, you might want to keep comments in the same language ;) I can read maybe a handful of German words (including the last 2 in that comment).

Comment: Oh sry. I just noticed :D i usually do ;) I said: i didn't change anything

Comment: `glDrawElements (...)` is not going to generate **1281** (`GL_INVALID_VALUE`) unless the count is negative. It's more than likely `glBindBuffer (...)` that is causing the problem. Have you verified that `this.iVBO` has a value generated by calling `glGenBuffers (...)`? I don't see any point in your code where this happens.

Comment: I generate them before. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: You haven't really answered Andon's observation though, could you please fill your code with glError checks to find where the GL_INVALID_VALUE actually comes from? Also, please post some more code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but i'll try to take a shot at it.

You never actually create the VAO, before binding the vertex array, you have to set the VAO to `vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();`.

When you put the array of data into the FloatBuffer, you don't need a for loop. It's as simple as `buffer.put(vertices);`.